# How do I solve this Olympiad question with floor functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Emmy is playing with a calculator. She enters an integer, and takes its square root. Then she repeats the process with the integer part of the answer. After the third repetition, the integer part equals 1 for the first time. What is the difference between the largest and the smallest number Emmy could have started with?
>
> $$
> \text{(A)} \; 229 \qquad
> \text{(B)} \; 231 \qquad
> \text{(C)} \; 239 \qquad
> \text{(D)} \; 241 \qquad
> \text{(E)} \; 254
> $$

This was Problem 19 from the first round of the [Norwegian Mathematical Olympiad, 2014–15](http://abelkonkurransen.no/en/problems/).

I think the floor function applies well here.

The integer part obviously is the floor part of it.

Let $x_1$ be the **initial.**

$x_2 = \left \lfloor{{\sqrt{x_1}}}\right \rfloor $

$x_3 = \left \lfloor{{\sqrt{x_2}}}\right \rfloor$

$x_4 = \left \lfloor{{\sqrt{x_3}}}\right \rfloor = 1$ <-- Last one.

So we need to find $b \le x_1 \le c$ such that $b$ is the smallest number to begin with and $c$ is the largest number to begin with.

$\sqrt{b} \le \sqrt{x_1} \le \sqrt{c}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly we must have $x_3<4$, $x_2<16$, and $x_1<256$, so the largest possible value of $x_1$ is $255$. Since $x_3>1$, we know that $x_3\ge 2$ and hence that $x_2\ge 4$. This implies that $x_1\ge 16$. Thus, the range is from $16$ through $255$, the difference being $239$.

Comment: @BrianScott, Thanks. Clear up, why must we have those conditions? Why $x_1 < 256$?

Comment: We know that $x_4=1$, so $1\le\sqrt{x_3}<2$, and therefore $x^3<2^2=4$. Now repeat the reasoning back up the line: $x_3<4$, so $\sqrt{x_2}<4$, and $x_2<16$. And so on.

Comment: @Robart: Sorry: I forgot to ping you with my answer. See the comment immediately above this one.

Comment: why cant she start with $x_1 = 1$ so the difference is $255 - 1 = 254$?

Comment: @Robart: Because we’re told that $x_4$ is the **first** of these integers to be equal to $1$.

Comment: Brian Scott, This is a great answer, can I ask something else? So how did you find the largest value? Did you use Meelo's method?

Comment: @Robart: Essentially, yes: if you think about my first comment up above, you’ll see that it’s basically an abbreviated description of that method.

Comment: Brian Scott, so, for the LOWER BOUND, 16, did you use trial/error?

Comment: @Robart: No, I used the same basic idea: $x_3$ has to be bigger than $1$, and it’s an integer, so it has to be at least $2$. Since it’s $\left\lfloor\sqrt{x_2}\right\rfloor$, that means that $\sqrt{x_2}$ has to be at least $2$, and therefore $x_2$ has to be at least $2^2=4$. Repeat this reasoning once, and you find that $x_1$ has to be at least $16$.

Comment: And then $x_3 = 4^2 = 16$?

Comment: @Robart: Not $x_3$: $x_1$. We have $x^2\ge 4$, but also $x_2=\left\lfloor\sqrt{x_1}\right\rfloor$, so $\left\lfloor\sqrt{x_1}\right\rfloor\ge 4$, which means that $\sqrt{x_1}\ge 4$. Now square both sides, and you have $x_1\ge 4^2=16$.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Robart: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We can work backwards more easily than we can work forwards. Firstly, what does a number $x$ need to satisfy to have
$\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$? Easy. We need:
$$1\leq x < 2.$$
Well, suppose that $\sqrt{y}=x$ or, equivalently, $y=x^2$. Well, obviously we just square the above equation (as all of its terms are positive):
$$1\leq x^2 < 2^2.$$
Suppose $\sqrt{z}=y$ or $z=y^2=x^4$. Square the above again!
$$1\leq x^4 < 2^4.$$
And finally let $\sqrt{w}=z$ or $w=z^2=y^4=x^8$. Square the above
$$1\leq x^8 < 2^8.$$

So, if she chose $z$ to be any integer in $[1,2^8)$, she will get $1$ as the final result. However, if $z$ were in the interval $[1,2^4)$, she would have gotten $1$ as the second result as well. So, we restrict ourselves to the integers in $[2^4,2^8)$, as these will satisfy the desired condition.

Comment: And how do you pick the smallesT? Its supposed to be $16$?

Comment: Yes, the condition that the third time is the first time that the number is $<2$ means that $x^2\geq 2$.

Comment: Why does it have to be $x^2 \ge 2$? then $x ge \sqrt{2}$

Comment: It should be 254 I believe. The smallest is $1$ since $\sqrt{1} = 1$ for $n$ square roots.

Comment: @Robart The question says that the third time is the *first* for which the result is $1$ - the greatest possible number is $255$, as higher numbers don't reach $1$ fast enough, and the least is $16$, as lower numbers reach $1$ too fast.